# SSIS - creating dynamically named log file using StartDate generates two log files

Tags: ssis

I have enabled file logging in an SSIS package and for the log file connection string I am using the expression below to generate a log file in the format `housekeepinglog2013_01_31_12_07.xml`

```
@[User::VAR_LOG_PATH] +"\\housekeepinglog" + 
(DATEDIFF( "dd", @[System::StartTime], GETDATE() ) < 1 ?
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , @[System::StartTime]) +  "_" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("mm", @[System::StartTime]), 2) + "_" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("dd", @[System::StartTime]), 2) +  "_" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("hh", @[System::StartTime]), 2) +  "_" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("mi", @[System::StartTime]), 2) +  "_" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("ss", @[System::StartTime]), 2)
: "") 
+ ".xml"
```

The issue is that instead of creating one log file I get two. One is complete with the correct date and another that contains just the log information on package validation but with a date that is about a day old.
It seems that the StartTime System variable  gets set once the package has started but this is done after validation and the validation is creating log entries. Before this the StartDate variable holds some arbitrary date that was created when editing the package.

It is only a minor irritation but I was wondering if anyone knew a non clunky way to supress the second log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the "older" looking log also has the `PackageStart` event too, yeah? What you are seeing here is somewhat related to the endeavor many try and that's to dynamically enable/disable logging on packages without modifying them. The challenge they run into is that the base dtexec.exe gets the package validated and all the that before you'd ever get into a place where your expressions begin to get validated.

The two options that come to mind are to provide the value for your connection string from the command line. Something like `dtexec /file .\mypackage.dtsx /set \Package.Connections[XmlLogCM].Properties[ConnectionString];\"c:\housekeepinglog_SomeDosSyntaxForDateTime.xml\"`

The second is to start the packages differently. Either through your custom .NET code using [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.aspx) or download and use [DTLoggedExec](http://dtloggedexec.codeplex.com/)